# Getting the last word of a text which contains only letter in php

Tags: php, regex

Can somebody help me to getting the last word from a text which contains only letters.

I should use regex I think...

For example:

```
100 r St Lazare, 75009 PARIS
```

I need the word `PARIS`

Answer (score 2):

If you want a **pure** regex solution, you can use

```
([a-z]+)$|^.*\b([a-z]+)\b
```

as your regex.
(Again, replace `[a-z]` with `[^\s\d]` if you're dealing with non-ascii chars)
[Demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/yC4vK5)

---

Essentially there are two cases:

1. A word consists only of letters *or* numbers. So there won't be a word like `Im1Word`.
   If this is the case, I'd go for

   ```
   /([a-z]+)$|([a-z]+)[^a-z]+$/i
   ```

   This will match `PARIS` in `100 r St Lazare, 75009 PARIS` and,
   for another example it will match `test` in `just a test 7509`.
   See the [demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/pL9gU3) (the `g` and `m` flags are just to match on multiple lines, so you see everything it would match).
2. A word consists of letters *and* numbers. There may be words like `Im1Word`.
   The above regex won't be enough and I would do this with some more logic in the code:

   ```
   $input = "100 r St Lazare, 75009 PARIS 123 abc123 123";
   $words = explode(' ', $input);

   for($i = count($words)-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
       if(preg_match("/\b[a-z]+\b/i",$words[$i]) == 1) {
           echo "Match: " . $words[$i];
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

   Essentially, we split the string by a space and iterate over each element from the end until the beginning. Whenever an element matches `\b[a-z]+\b` we found last word consisting only of letters.
   [Example @ ideone](http://ideone.com/TKqEQs)

Now, if you have any non-ascii characters both of the above solutions will fail.
You need to change both regexes:

1. `([^\s\d]+)$|([^\s\d]+)[\s\d]+$`
2. `"/\b[^\s\d]+\b/i"`

This way you will match non-ascii words, too.

Comment: what about "this just a tes1t 7509"???

Comment: @naveengoyal I don't think this will occur, but nevertheless a good point. added a solution to my answer

Comment: This works for `"this just a tes1t 7509"` now, but still only feeds on plain ASCII – which is insufficient for two thirds of SO users. Maybe the correct answer is some combination of this added version and my answer.

Comment: @feeela if you're going for non-ascii characters in combination with a word consisting of letters and numbers, simply replace `[a-z]` with `[^\s\d]` in the php code in my example. (yea, actually this is a combination of our answers)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
$input = '100 r St Lazare, 75009 PARIS';
$words = explode(' ', $input);
$last  = array_pop($words);
```

or

```
$last  = $words[count($words) - 1];
```

Comment: "which contains only letter" – what about `$input = '100 r St Lazare, 75009 PARIS 546';`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest the following version, though it is still not perfect for all cases:

```
$input = '100 r St Lazare, 75009 PARIS 345'; // pass, returns "PARIS"
$input = '100 r St Lazare, 75009 PARIS';     // pass, returns "PARIS"
$input = 'this just a Ðöæ 75009';            // pass, returns "Ðöæ"
$input = 'this just a Ðöæ';                  // pass, returns "Ðöæ"
$input = 'this just a tes1t 75009';          // fail, returns "t"

$output = array();
preg_match( '/([^\s\d]+)[\s\d]*$/i', $input, $output );
$lastWordThatConsistsOnlyOfLetters = array_pop( $output );

var_dump( $lastWordThatConsistsOnlyOfLetters );
```

(@naveengoyal The test string you've posted is a hard one…)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions and `explode` are possible solutions, however, the fastest one is `substr` in my opinion:

```
$last = substr($words, strrpos($words, " ")+1);
```

`strrpos` returns the offset of last space. That's all you need.

Answer (score -1):

you may try

```
$text = "100 r St Lazare, 75009 PARIS";
$exploded = explode(" ",$text);
echo $exploded[count($exploded)-1]
```